# App Academy coding-test-2 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While working through the app academy coding-test-1 problem sets, everything worked wonderfully! Then, as soon as I try to load the first problem in coding-test-2, I receive an error. Can anybody please tell me what this error means and how to troubleshoot it? The response from the console is pasted below:

```
marceldegas@prep-work:~/workspace/coding-test-2/practice-problems/lib (master) $ ruby 01_no_repeats.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 01_no_repeats (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from 01_no_repeats.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post the file structure of the files you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I believe you are passing the wrong argument to the terminal.

To run the spec file, you want to use the command:

bundle exec rspec spec/01_no_repeats_spec.rb

notice the inclusion of the "_spec" in the file name and the precursory bundle exec rspec

Hope this works!